# I Want Frequency Value with the Maximum Sample Using R

Tags: r, apply, frequency

I want the frequency with the maximum samples in `df`

```
df <- data.frame(Freq = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Valu = c(10,5,11,7,13,15,9,6,12,12))


apply(df, 2, which.max)
```

.

**What I want**

I want it to print just the frequency of the maximum `Valu` which is `6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `which.max` on the column 'Sample', get the index and extract (`[`), the corresponding 'Freq' value

```
with(df, Freq[which.max(Valu)])
#[1] 6
```

If the column names are changing, then use position index

```
df[[1]][which.max(df[[2]])]
[1] 6
```

Or may use `order` as well

```
df[[1]][order(-df[[2]])][1]
[1] 6
```

---

If we loop over the columns (`*apply`) with `MARGIN = 2` and apply the function `which.max`, it returns the index of `max` for those columns separately

Comment: I just want a syntax that will use only the `data frame and not going back to the `sample` that generates it.

Comment: @DanielJames is this because the column names are different.  Then, use `mydf[[1]][which.max(mydf[[2]])]`

Comment: @DanielJames I didn't understsand what you meant by `not going back`..  Can you describe a bit more

Comment: I have edited the formation of my data frame to make you understand my question beter

Comment: @DanielJames what is the issue with using `df[[1]][which.max(df[[2]])]
[1] 6`

Comment: permit me to edit your syntax to reflect changes in my question for others to understand that your answer addresses my question.

Comment: @DanielJames you can go ahead and edit it. thanks

Comment: The `suggested edit queue is full`, please change `mydf` to `df` in your answer as I can no longer edit it

Comment: i updatd the post